# Unable to create foreign key constraint for a table

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKWmu.png)I am unable to create foreign key constraint for the table

Unable to create foreign key constraint

```
CREATE TABLE dept ( DNO INT NOT NULL primary key, 
DNAME varchar(15) not null, 
Location varchar(15) not null, 
NumEmp int not null,
Managers int not null, 
Foreign key (DNO) references employee (DNO) );

create table employee ( SSN CHAR(9) NOT NULL primary key, 
FNAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
MINIT VARCHAR(5), 
LNAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
BDATE DATE, ADDRESS VARCHAR(30), 
SEX CHAR, SALARY DECIMAL(10,2), 
SUPERSSN CHAR(9), 
DNO INT NOT NULL )
```

Comment: That’s the wrong way round, the FK should in employee referencing dept

Answer (score 1):

You try to create a foreign key reference to a table that does not exist (since you create `dept` first).
**But** the real issue here is that the [`foreign key`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) should be placed in the table `employee` and **not** in `dept`:

```
CREATE TABLE dept ( 
  DNO INT NOT NULL primary key, 
  DNAME varchar(15) not null, 
  Location varchar(15) not null, 
  NumEmp int not null, 
  Managers int not null
);

CREATE TABLE employee ( 
  SSN CHAR(9) NOT NULL primary key, 
  FNAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
  MINIT VARCHAR(5), 
  LNAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
  BDATE DATE, 
  ADDRESS VARCHAR(30), 
  SEX CHAR, 
  SALARY DECIMAL(10,2), 
  SUPERSSN CHAR(9), 
  DNO INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (DNO) REFERENCES dept (DNO)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create the employee table first and then create the dept table. this will work